# Is there a easy way to configure users and settings across multiple operating systems?

Tags: configuration, automation, operating-system, user-accounts, configuration-management

I install a lot of operating systems (both Linux and Windows) on VMs. After the install, I would like to setup some common users and groups on the machine. These users and settings would be common across all the machines. Is there a tool that lets me do this on Linux and Windows? It need not be the same tool on both the platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want is a Configuration Managment Tool like Puppet or Chef (for example).

I can't suggest you the ideal software for your needs because I don't have a lot of details.

I think that the best way to approach the problem is to read the wikipedia article about "[Comparison of open source configuration management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software)".

The first table refers to the '[Basic properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software#Basic_properties)' and the second table to the '[Platform support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software#Platform_support)' (I think that the Linux and Windows column is interesting for you).

A '[Short description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software#Short_descriptions)' for each tool is available. I think it's interesting to read this section if you want to get an idea of the tools more or less easily affordable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will let you guys know what I use.